# How to get object data and push an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an endpoint that returns an object. The object is:

```
{
"id": "669f8",
"creation_date": "2022-01-13 10:33:06.046652+01:00",
"case_type": "Summary",
"process_types": "",
"case_id": "ad23423s",
"current_stage": "",
"current_stage_name": "",
"consolidation": "None",
"last_change_date": "2022-01-14 14:35:17.563449+01:00",
"status": 1,
"assign": "Yes"
```

}
I want to display it in my React project.
Firstly I want to take object fields, and then the values.

I wrote this code:

```
class DetailsPage extends React.Component<DetailProps> {
  async getData() {
    const data = await Dependencies.backend.getList(this.props.url);
    if (data) {
      return data;
    }
    return [];
  }
  render() {
    const data = this.getData()
    const fields: string[][] = []
    const test: any[] = []
    data.then((val: any) =>
      fields.push(Object.keys(val))
      // console.log(val)
    )  .catch(err => console.log("There was an error:" + err))
    console.log("testeststt")
    console.log(fields)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hoi!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `console.log(fields)` returns
[]

And when I open the array it shows

[image: output]

But I can't get the 0th row.

How can I get and push another array or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that the `render` function only renders out the UI. It is not supposed to make asynchronous stuff. Since, you need to invoke the API call when the component mounts, you can do it in `componentDidMount` and when you have `data`, update it in state.

This way, on the initial render, you will have 0 items in the `data`. When you update the state, it will re-render the component and then you will have items in your `data`.

You can do something like the following:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.getData()
}

async getData() {
  const data = await Dependencies.backend.getList(this.props.url);
  this.setState({ data: data ?? [] })
}

render() {
  const { data } = this.state;
  console.log(data)
}
```